# Fetch Mysql data order according to in Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Suppose;

**table name**: user

```
╔═══╦══════╦════╗
║ id║ name ║ age║
╠═══╬══════╬════╣
║ 5 ║ a    ║ 25 ║
║ 8 ║ b    ║ 12 ║
║ 10║ c    ║ 13 ║
║ 12║ d    ║ 16 ║
║ 14║ e    ║ 21 ║
╚═══╩══════╩════╝
```

Query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE id IN (12,4,14,5,10);
```

now Question is data comes ASC but i want to get data according to the order of (12,4,14,5,10).
Any Solution.

Comment: Did you try without using `ASC` command ??

Comment: What does that order represent?  Are you trying to get the data in age ascending or name ascending, or something else?  Or random?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `field()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE id IN (12, 4, 14, 5, 10)
ORDER BY field(id, 12, 4, 14, 5, 10);
```

Comment: I think they are too busy to check the answer properly. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can Use [`Field()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) Operator.  Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list. Returns 0 if str is not found.

```
WHERE id IN([ids any order])
ORDER BY FIELD(id, [ids in order])
```